# Filter CSS is lost when printing in Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-filters

I have an image with the following css rule:

```
filter: invert(100%)
```

In Edge, when printing, this filter is lost. It's not lost on Chrome, and my understanding is that css is not supposed to be lost when printing. I've tried different filters and they face the same problem.

I've tried using -webkit-filter instead, and I've tried using -ms-filter, but neither of these have helped.

Is there a way to get Edge's printing functionality to adhere to the filter css?

Comment: What do you mean by printing? What version of Edge are you using, as filter should be supported :  https://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: @JackDalton The filter does show up in normal view, but when I print (ctrl+p) the filter is lost. This is Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is an issue with Edge browser. I have tested using different image formats, and media queries like "@media print {}" but nothing seems to have any effect. I would suggest posting on Edge bug forums.